# What happens when you mmap the same large file by multiple processes?

Tags: c++, linux, memory, file-io, mmap

Say the mmap call is something like this:

```cpp
auto fd = ::open("somelargefile", O_RDONLY);
struct stat sb;
fstat(fd, &sb);
const auto memblock = ::mmap(NULL, sb.st_size, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, fd, 0);
```

If I spawn multiple processes for with this same code snippet... is there any overhead memory wise? does a new mapping get created everytime and each process has separate read mapping?

If the problem is to read huge files, and different processes reading same file at the same time, can it optimized with mmap?

Edit:
When I do run multiple processes with this, then all of them show up taking similar amount of RES and SHR memory in top. The SHR is replica of the RES.

Comment: Why don't you use `read` or its variants?

Comment: @curiousguy I suppose he wants to read into a shared memory to optimize the reads since multiple processes are involved. I am not entirely sure but simply reading data from the file in each process may have a memory overhead proportional to the number of processes reading it, not to mention unnecessary kernel calls.

Comment: As @MutableSideEffect explains. The number of processes is high, hundreds of them, reading one same file, consider a packet dump (pcap). Since the time taken by the process to finish is IO bound, I was thinking mmap can help.

Comment: Considering there’s a specific option to make it shared or private it is logical that it is shared between processes if so desired. If it’s private it is copy-on-write based on documentation, so only reading should still share the memory

Comment: The manpage doesn't say anything about sharing read when MAP_SHARED enabled.

Comment: @themagicalyang strange that you are mapping the complete "large file" into memory. Is there some reason for doing that? Even if the file is not read during the mmap call, you are reserving a large part of your address space.

Comment: @MutableSideEffect I honestly just picked it up because of an example already had that. I am not sure what are the side effects of that.

Comment: @themagicalyang: The interesting question here is whether `MAP_PRIVATE` does reflect changes to the file in practice, since then it would be realized as the kernel’s buffers for the file in question.